# Rails strips html class tag from button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have the following in my view:

```
      <%= button_to 'Check In', controller: "posts", action: :check_in, id: @post.id, :class => "btn", :style => "display:inline" %>
```

For some reason, the :class and :style do not end up in the HTML that is rendered.  I have tried putting this class and style on other ERB tags and they get rendered from there.  Why are they being stripped on this tag only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`button_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)`

so, you need to wrap the options and html_options attributes to hashes

`<%= button_to 'Check In', { controller: "posts", action: :check_in, id: @post.id }, { :class => "btn", :style => "display:inline" } %>`

Answer (score 0):

Many tag helpers require HTML attributes to be in a `:html` key.

```
<%= button_to 'Check In', controller: "posts", action: :check_in, id: @post.id, :html => {:class => "btn", :style => "display:inline"} %>
```